# Using VB for Excel, copying a sheet to another sheet when cell is edited gets an error

Tags: excel, vba

Using VB for Excel, my objective is that when a cell, any cell  is edited in the sheet, the macro copies the entire sheet to a different sheet and then goes back to the original sheet, but I am getting an error at the select statement.

How do I fix this?

```
Private Sub worksheet_change(ByVal Target As Range)

Cells.Select

    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Tempsheet").Select
    Range("A1:C1").Select   ***'run time error 1004, select method of range class failed***
    ActiveSheet.Buttons.Add(388.5, 47, 42, 17.5).Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Sheets("MainSheet").Select
End Sub
```

Comment: It would be much better to [avoid using Select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba).

Comment: Need to explain the button...

Comment: ignore the button code , it is just copying a button on the main sheet